# Bluetooth LE: triggering pin pairing on characteristic in iOS

Tags: android, ios, encryption, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a Bluetooth PCB that has an encrypted characteristic. Whenever I connect to the main service iOS requests me to **insert the pairing pin**. However, if I choose to ignore this and try to access the encrypted characteristic iOS won't allow to read the values and won't ask me to input the pairing pin.

**However in Android** the OS prompts me with a notification to insert the pin when accessing the encrypted characteristic.

So it is clearly an OS level implementation detail. Am I missing something? **Is there a way to get iOS to prompt requesting the PIN in encrypted characteristics whenever a pairing had not happened**?

Official documentation reference or code example will greatly help.